# How could I shorten this translator script?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a JavaScript translator, but after writing out a couple words, I realised this would take forever, especially if I would want to do more than 20 words. Are there any ways to make this script shorter so I could have the user enter more words without me spending too much time adding a translation process for more than 20 variables.

The script below takes the content of a text box, separates it into variables, makes sure no variables are undefined, and goes through a seperate translation process for each word before placing the translated content back into the text box. I have not included the HTML because it's not important. 
So, my quesiton is, **How can I shorten this script to be able to translate more words without spending the rest of my life doing it.**

```
/* The Translator */

function myFunction() {  //yeah I gotta use funtion myFunction... I lack creativity
var x = document.getElementById("translateinput").value;


//splitting the string into variables
var w1 = x.split(" ")[0];
var w2 = x.split(" ")[1];
var w3 = x.split(" ")[2];
var w4 = x.split(" ")[3];
var w5 = x.split(" ")[4];
var w6 = x.split(" ")[5];
var w7 = x.split(" ")[6];
var w8 = x.split(" ")[7];
var w9 = x.split(" ")[8];
var w10 = x.split(" ")[9];
var w11 = x.split(" ")[10];
var w12 = x.split(" ")[11];
var w13 = x.split(" ")[12];
var w14 = x.split(" ")[13];
var w15 = x.split(" ")[14];
var w16 = x.split(" ")[15];
var w17 = x.split(" ")[16];
var w18 = x.split(" ")[17];
var w19 = x.split(" ")[18];
var w20 = x.split(" ")[19];

 //making sure nothing is undefined in case the string is less than 20 words
 if (typeof w1 == "undefined") {
w1 = ""
  }
 if (typeof w2 == "undefined") {
      w2 = ""
 }
 if (typeof w3 == "undefined") {
     w3 = ""
 }
 if (typeof w4 == "undefined") {
     w4 = ""
 }
 if (typeof w5 == "undefined") {
     w5 = ""
 }
 if (typeof w6 == "undefined") {
     w6 = ""
 }
 if (typeof w7 == "undefined") {
     w7 = ""
 }
 if (typeof w8 == "undefined") {
     w8 = ""
 }
 if (typeof w9 == "undefined") {
     w9 = ""
 }
 if (typeof w10 == "undefined") {
     w10 = ""
 }
 if (typeof w11 == "undefined") {
    w11 = ""
 }
 if (typeof w12 == "undefined") {
     w12 = ""
 }
 if (typeof w13 == "undefined") {
     w13 = ""
 }
 if (typeof w14 == "undefined") {
     w14 = ""
 }
 if (typeof w15 == "undefined") {
     w15 = ""
 }
if (typeof w16 == "undefined") {
     w16 = ""
 }
 if (typeof w17 == "undefined") {
     w17 = ""
 }
 if (typeof w18 == "undefined") {
     w18 = ""
 }
 if (typeof w19 == "undefined") {
     w19 = ""
 }
 if (typeof w20 == "undefined") {
     w20 = ""
 }

 //The translation process
 if (w1 === "word1")
 {
    var w1 = "word2"
 }
 if (w2 === "word1")
 {
     var w2 = "word2"
 }
 if (w3 === "word1")
 {
    var w3 = "word2"
 }
 if (w4 === "word1")
 {
    var w4 = "word2"
 }
 if (w5 === "word1")
 {
    var w5 = "word2"
 }
 if (w6 === "word1")
 {
    var w6 = "word2"
 }
 if (w6 === "word1")
 {
    var w6 = "word2"
 }
 if (w7 === "word1")
 {
     var w7 = "word2"
 }
 if (w8 === "word1")
 {
    var w8 = "word2"
 }
 if (w9 === "word1")
  {
    var w9 = "word2"
 }
 if (w10 === "word1")
 {
     var w10 = "word2"
 }
 if (w11 === "word1")
 {
    var w11 = "word2"
 }
 if (w12 === "word1")
 {
     var w12 = "word2"
 }
 if (w13 === "word1")
 {
    var w13 = "word2"
 }
 if (w14 === "word1")
{
    var w14 = "word2"
 }
 if (w15 === "word1")
{
     var w15 = "word2"
}
 if (w16 === "word1")
{
    var w16 = "word2"
 }
 if (w17 === "word1")
{
    var w17 = "word2"
  }
  if (w18 === "word1")
{
    var w18 = "word2"
 }
 if (w19 === "word1")
 {
    var w19 = "word2"
  }
 if (w20 === "word1")
 {
    var w20 = "word2"
 }


//resulting translated string
 var result = w1 + " " + w2 + " " + w3 + " " + w4 + " " + w5 + " " + w6 + " " + w7 + " " + w8 + " " + w9 + " " + w10 + " " + w11 + " " + w12 + " " + w13 + " " + w14 + " " + w15 + " " + w16 + " " + w17 + " " + w18 + " " + w19 + " " + w20


//places final result back into text box
   document.getElementById("translateinput").value = result;
}
```

Comment: Shortening your code is easy; you just need to use loops. However, it's not clear from your example what you want to translate and what it should be translated to. If you just want to replace all occurrences of one word in a string with another word, you can just use the String.replace() function.

Comment: Looks like you need to learn about arrays. Step 1: `var words = x.split(" ");`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace all occurrences of one word in a string with another word, you can use the built-in String.replace() function:

```
x.replace('word1', 'word2')    // replaces only one occurrence    
x.replace(/word1/gi, 'word2'); // replaces all occurrences (needs a regular expression)
```

If you need to do something else with the split words, then you can loop over an array:

```
var words = x.split(" ");
for (var w in words) {
    console.log(words[w]);
    // do other stuff with the word here.
}
```

See the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You may read about array in JavaScript and understand loop usage

Here are the changes you  may do to the function

1. Keep the translation mapping in a js object

   trans_obj = {"word1":"word11" , "word2":"word22"}
2. Instead of splitting text by space and storing in different variables you may just use the array as such
3. Use map to translate every element of array and join the array later

**Implementaion**

```js
function translate(str) {
  var tr = {
    word1: "word11",
    word2: "word22",
    word3: "word33",
    hello: "holla"
  };
  var str_list = str.split(/\s/);
  for (var i = 0; i < str_list.length; i++) {
    str_list[i] = tr[str_list[i]] || str_list[i];
  }
  return str_list.join(" ");
}

console.log(translate("word1 is neither word2 nor word3"));
console.log(translate("hello world1"));
```

You may use regular expression also for the same ,here is a regular expression implementation

**Regex Implementation**

```js
function translate(str) {
  var mapObj = {
    word1: "word11",
    word2: "word22",
    word3: "word33",
    hello: "holla"
  };

  var re = new RegExp(Object.keys(mapObj).join("|"), "gi");

  return str.replace(re, function(matched) {
    return mapObj[matched.toLowerCase()];
  });
}


console.log(translate("word1 is neither word2 nor word3"));
console.log(translate("hello world1"));
```